# WiFi limitations

Tags: audio, wifi, sampling

What are the limitations of using WiFi where you have, say, 30+ clients/devices pushing compressed audio (flac)?

Bitrates: ~384 to 768 kb/s (44100 x 16 x 1 to 48000 x 16 x 1) * ( 0.5 to 1.0 )
(sampling rate) * (bit depth) * (number of channels) * (compression)

I'm sure that I can stream more than 1 client, but I'm not sure how figure out what my boundaries are and what tradeoffs I can make.

I'm sure a noisy wifi environment will create greater limitations, but what are the other limitations I will run into?

Basically what I want to know is how many channels of streaming audio data (@ ~768 kbit/s) will an 802.11n router (600 Mbit/s) handle?

~780? <== that seems like a lot.

Comment: The reason I ask is I am thinking about designing some hardware that needs wireless communication and I want to see if wifi is the a good solution. I will also try superuser or serverfault, but if anyone has experience please let me know.

Comment: That sounds reasonable here then, your question sure didn't sound like that is what you were doing though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my day job I design equipment that streams lots of audio over Ethernet.  By "lots of audio", we have one device that does 512 audio inputs and 512 audio outputs of UNCOMPRESSED, 24-bit, 48 KHz, low-latency audio.  When you include data overhead and stuff, this means that we're transferring about 900 megabits/second, both directions, over a single GigE wired link.  I mention this because, well, I know a thing or two about sending lots of audio over a network.

Every now and then a customer of ours will ask about audio over WiFi.  Our response is always the same:  we won't do it!  WiFi just isn't reliable for this sort of thing.  Sure, you might be able to get X audio channels right this second, but just about anything can mess that up.  There are the obvious things like someone starting up a microwave oven, but it could also be the big truck that just parked outside of your building causing some multipath distortion.  Or how about the guy messing around with his iPhone trying to stream cat videos on YouTube.

We have seen cases where your WiFi bandwidth can go from the full 54 mbps to 0 and back again.  Depending on your application maybe this is acceptable, or maybe not.  For my application (professional audio) it is certainly not acceptable.

So, to answer your question of how many audio channels you can get over WiFi the answer is:  Anywhere from None to Many.  I know that's not a useful answer, but it is the only honest answer you can get.  You can actually try it and measure what you get, but even that would not be accurate since there are many things outside of your control that could affect it.

If you can tolerate some buffering and other "availability" issues then you can probably stream quite a bit more-- enough to be useful.  But even then it's impossible to say how many channels you can get.

**Edit:  Added stuff about, theoretically, how you would get 30+ channels of professional audio to stream wirelessly.**

Let's start by defining what it means to have "professional audio streaming".  A defining feature, if you ask me, is a low and consistent latency.  Consistent is more important than low.  You don't want the same audio coming out of several speakers and have it all out of phase.  You also don't want it coming out of the speakers several hundred milliseconds later.

With compressed audio, like MP3 and other similar things, you can easily get 0.1 to 10.0 seconds of latency.  To make matters worse, standard WiFi (like 802.11x) can easily add another 0.01 to 0.100 seconds of latency.  In some scenarios, latency of 0.02 seconds can be heard, so the latency of either compressed audio or audio over WiFi is often way too much.

Now, let's talk about radio waves...  This is a "shared medium", meaning that everyone and their cousin shares the same bandwidth.  Copper wire, on the other hand, is not shared.  You have complete control over what the wire is used for and you have no control over the radio waves.  In short, you are never going to have "mission critical" reliability going over radio waves-- especially WiFi where everyone is carrying a WiFi radio in their pocket.

The closest thing to reliable pro-audio over radio waves is the wireless microphone technology.  There are a couple of reasons why this works and WiFi doesn't.  1: They are using radio frequencies that are largely unused by normal consumers (a.k.a. smartphone owners).  2:  They can select from a wide range of frequencies to find the best one.  3: Each audio channel gets its own RF channel.  4: Until very recently they all transmitted in analog, meaning that when the RF degraded it usually degraded gracefully where the audio was still useful if a little noisy.

Another method that I've used is with dedicated laser based links between buildings.  While wireless, this is only point-to-point and is unsuitable for connecting many things together.

So, the way that you do 30+ channels of audio wirelessly is to create your own WiFi technology that uses RF frequencies that are more or less dedicated to your application.  Even then, it's not easy.

There is a lot of money to be made by the first company that can put lots of pro-audio channels on WiFi reliably.  Many have tried, but all have failed so far.

Comment: Also be aware of the limited number of simultaneous channels that can be handled on 802.11xxx. This varies with version but reduces to closer to 0 than will be comfortable in higher bandwidth versions.

Comment: My interest is in professional audio as well. How would you suggest I get 30+ channels of audio streaming wirelessly?

Comment: @Hair_of_the_Dog  I added stuff to my answer about this.

Comment: David, consider that 802.11n goes in the 5GHz band, that should suffer a bit less interference, especially from microwave ovens. Maybe not enough to be reliable, but I would like to know how much better.

Comment: @clabacchio I can't tell you how much better, but I know it's not better in any useful way.  Imagine this:  You're running sound for 100k people at a stadium and the game hasn't started yet.  You now have 100k people who are potentially bored and are holding their 802.11n smartphone.  That's a lot of interference!  Even if only 500 of them are actively messing with things, that's still a lot.  Now imagine the audio cutting out for 1 second every 1 minute, and what 100k annoyed drunk people can do.  If the audio cut out that much, probably a lot of people would get their ticket refunded.

Comment: There are 802.11n smartphones?? Anyway I agree that a solution is the use of non-standard frequencies.

Comment: @clabacchio My Samsung Galaxy S2 has 802.11a/b/g/n and the iPhone 4s has b/g/n.

Comment: Wow...so young and so old... :(

Comment: Why not just make it a private/hidden network if you're worried about people stealing your bandwidth? If you're worried about frequency overlap, mix it to a different ISM band.

Comment: @JoelB There are many ways to steal bandwidth without knowing the network SSID.  A Microwave Oven, for example, doesn't know anything about WiFi but could interfere with it.  You could go to a different ISM band, but then it wouldn't be 802.11x compliant, you complicate spectrum licensing, and you still don't get rid of sources of interference that can take away bandwidth (you only reduce interference, not eliminate it).

Comment: I  find this topic highly interesting and would like to know whether things have changed at all in the past years, e.g. due to improvements in signal processing?

Comment: I’ve been tinkering with this application of wifi and essentially the only way to do it reliably is to have full control of the WiFi stack. An expensive proposition both due to licensing and development costs. That’s the only way to get full usable bandwidth out of the over-the-air channel without glitches due to protocol interactions across layers etc. The RF channel is still subject to interference and that will cause data loss. But at least you’ll get some bandwidth back once a transient is over, without the stack having to recover. In presence of public… it has no chance of working.